# Regex - string ends with <br>

Tags: php, regex

I have a string made of urls and separated by `<br>` tags. Im using this regex to match the urls: `/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/g`

The above matches the entire string which is not what I want. I need the urls without the 
 tags.

I have tried adding replacing `(\/\S*)` with `(<br>\/\S)` but it returns wrong results.

What is the correct solution?

Example url list:

```
http://www.google.com/explearning/4a1f519153c809a424ee2d3ed93b685a<br>http://www.google.com/explearning/e3fa4315175288ea85b7682c34d9f504<br>http://www.google.com/explearning/e818d4fd6d546844d63fb9e160cf046e<br>http://www.google.com/explearning/5d4c6b570e6bfa918b7b4be14cc41a42<br>http://www.google.com/explearning/adf3d853c1bb4f5f30efc64802c30d75<br>
```

Comment: `$urls = explode('<br>', $string);`

Comment: then `preg_split('/<br>/', $string);`

Comment: `(\/\S*)?(<br>)?/g` probably with modifier U

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: Oh! see AbraCadaver answer.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I dont need to use explode or preg_split. using preg_match_all with a good enough regex should take care of it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I was responding to OP's comment saying they needed to use a regex by doing the same as Abra but with a regex.

Comment: @Cheery: the g modifier doesn't exist in php, "probably with the U modifier" is probably an interesting information.

Comment: And could you post an example of the list of urls to work with?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn It doesnt matter really. But see the updated post anyhow

Comment: @NuGnojMik: your approach is bad and slow, `explode` will solve the problem faster.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That wasnt the question I had. Performance is not a concern

Comment: `Example url list:` why do you need regexp for that???

Comment: `~(?:https?|ftps?)://(?:(?!<br>).)+~s` or `~(?:https?|ftps?)://\S+?(?=<br>|$)~`

Comment: I was about to post pretty much exactly what hwnd just did except I had a `.+?` instead of `\S+?`. Either way you end up with the same results.

Comment: @NuGnojMik: I know, but what you want to do doesn't appear very clearly in your question. If I make an explorer work, I will deduct: "how to split and check urls". So the good way to do that is to split first and to check the urls after. But checking an url with a pattern is near that impossible. So the best way is to use something else (an url `checker`)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to extract urls from your string is to use explode, and then, if you want to test if each parts are valid urls, you can use `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`, example:

```
$parts = explode('<br>', $yourstring);
$urls = array();

foreach($parts as $part) {
    if(filter_var($part, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
        $urls[] = $part;
}
```

If you want to check that your string is only composed of urls separated with `<br>` tags, you only need to compare the `$parts` length with the `$urls` length. If the two lengths are equal, the string is as you want. 
But you can make the foreach loop more performant. When a part is not an url, you can stop the foreach loop:

```
$parts = explode('<br>', $yourstring);
$urls = array();

foreach($parts as $part) {
    if(filter_var($part, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
        $urls[] = $part;
    else break;
}

if (count($parts) == count($urls))
    print_r($urls);
```

Comment: Even though OP states regex, this is a more effective approach IMO.

Comment: Only problem is that I cannot guarantee that the list is purely urls and <br> tags.

Comment: @NuGnojMik: I understand, but what do you want to do if substrings separated by "<br>" are not urls? Finding urls in these substrings is near than impossible with a pattern and an sane brain. But if your string is not like you describe it in your question, please add more informations about how it looks.